# In WebStorm with TypeScript, How to Debug While TS errors?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I need to debug my node program by launching server.js first (not server.ts). This means, I want my typescript compiled first, but I don't want it to stop (abort) on typescript errors that I will fix later. Now, webstorm stops when I try and debug.

How can I make it keep going?

Comment: Just an idea: in your build step do `tsc ... || true`?

Comment: Debugging is not terminated because of compiler errors, so I have no idea what you are talking about. Please record a video that shows your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add typescript compiler to **Before launch** section of your run configuration? If yes, you need to disable **Check errors** in Typescript compiler settings there, otherwise the application won't be launched if compiler errors are reported:

[image]

Comment: I did what you suggest, I see "compiling typescript" go by in my status bar, yet it does not compile my root file server.ts. I know this because if I change that file, then debug, the old server.js is being used. When I manually `tsc server.ts`, debug again, I get the new one.

Comment: works for me - changed files are re-compiled when running the debug configuration

Comment: You are JetBrains? Can I create a ticket through webstorm and let you know a link to it? I'd want to make it a private ticket as I'm not ready to publish to the world my source at the moment

Comment: sure, please create a [support ticket](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) - all information you provide there will be kept private

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tslint for your js file.
https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/rule-flags/.

Other option, is convert server.js to server.ts and add some typings, and compile this to js file.

Comment: I want the errors, I just want the WebStorm to start debugging even though there are TypeScript errors. That is, typescript errors that don't prevent the JavaScript from working correctly.  For example, when I enter the command ts-node server.ts, my app runs, but when I try to debug with webstorm, it does not.